# Generate all possible arithmetic solutions and then determine which are essential the "same"

Tags: python

I'm looking to code a variant of the card game 24 in Python, but would like the user to offer up, say, 4 "unique" solutions using all 4 given numbers using the operators: +-*/. As of now, the user does not have access to parenthesis and the equation evaluates from left to right.

So far, I have code that would give me all the possible solutions below. However, I'm struggling with the next step where I need to match up the ones that are the "same".

For example: A+B+C+D is the same as B+C+D+A, or A+B+C-D is the same as B-C+A+B, or A * B-C+D is the same as B*A+D-C. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations, combinations_with_replacement, product


given_numbers_string = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']


operators = ["+","-","*","/"]

solution_space =  {}

seen = set()

for values in permutations(given_numbers_string,len(given_numbers_string)):
    for operCombo in combinations_with_replacement(operators,len(given_numbers_string)-1):
        for oper in permutations(operCombo,len(given_numbers_string)-1):
            formula = "".join(o+v for o,v in zip([""]+list(oper),values))
            if formula not in seen:
                solution_space[formula] = 0
print(solution_space, len(solution_space))

def function():
    global solution_space
    
    given_numbers = [1,2,3,4]
    
    given_numbers_string = list(map(str, given_numbers))
    
    target = 24
    operators = ["+","-","*","/"]
    
    solution_counter = 0
    for values in permutations(given_numbers_string,len(given_numbers_string)):
        for operCombo in combinations_with_replacement(operators,len(given_numbers_string)-1):
            for oper in permutations(operCombo,len(given_numbers_string)-1):
                formula = "".join(o+v for o,v in zip([""]+list(oper),values))
                if formula not in solution_space and isinstance(eval(formula),int):
                    solution_space[(formula)] = 1
                    if eval(formula)==target:
                        print(formula,"=",eval(formula))
                        solution_counter += 1

    
    solution_space = {}
    return(given_numbers, solution_counter)

function()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "match up"?

Comment: @alexpdev "match up" would mean that once a user entered A+B+C+D, solutions like B+C+D+A would be tagged as used. So if the given numbers were [1,2,3,4], I would want to "match up" 1*2*3*4 as the "same" as 2*3*4*1, 3*4*2*1, etc... so that when a user enters a valid solution, in the background, all of the other, "same" solutions would no longer be valid. Does this make sense?

Comment: You would need to define those rules in code and then implement them as checks in a recursive backtracking algorithm.  Or at least that is how I would do it.